# Is there something wrong with these unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, xunit, stub

I was reading an article by Martin Fowler ([Mocks Aren't Stubs](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)) and there's this Java test at the beginning:

```
public class OrderStateTester extends TestCase {
  private static String TALISKER = "Talisker";
  private static String HIGHLAND_PARK = "Highland Park";
  private Warehouse warehouse = new WarehouseImpl();

  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    warehouse.add(TALISKER, 50);
    warehouse.add(HIGHLAND_PARK, 25);
  }
  public void testOrderIsFilledIfEnoughInWarehouse() {
    Order order = new Order(TALISKER, 50);
    order.fill(warehouse);
    assertTrue(order.isFilled());
    assertEquals(0, warehouse.getInventory(TALISKER));
  }
  public void testOrderDoesNotRemoveIfNotEnough() {
    Order order = new Order(TALISKER, 51);
    order.fill(warehouse);
    assertFalse(order.isFilled());
    assertEquals(50, warehouse.getInventory(TALISKER));
  }
```

My understanding of this code is that a `WarehouseImpl` is created at the beginning (`setUp()`) and used in two tests, both of which manipulate the `WarehouseImpl` object. So the tests are affecting each other and the order in which they are run could potentially affect the outcomes.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hint: turn to Junit4. Junit3 and extending Testcases; thats almost like last millennium.

Answer (score 3):

No. each test is independent with others. since the junit will creates a brand-new  instance for each `@Test` method. so they don't affect the outcomes in each test unless the test access a **static** field.

Comment: I think your answer isn't fully correct; there is more than one problem with it.

Comment: @GhostCat Hi, I'm not say the OP using junit4, I just use an annotation make make the `test` distinguished with test class.

Comment: You are using an annotation that only works for JUnit4; whilst answering a question that uses JUnit3. Again: you are throwing two things together that do not make sense together. You should at least make that more explicit!

Comment: @GhostCat sir, is that important? I only uses it for the distinguish purpose.

Comment: Obviously I found it important enough to tell you. What is the point of writing incomplete, misleading answers!?

Comment: @GhostCat I'm sorry I confused you. thanks for your feedback too much, sir. but you can see I have never wrote down the word `junit4` in my answer.